# WP Members additional fields on user profile

Tags: plugins, functions, filters

i want to have a limited set of fields during the registration process, but would still like additional fields available for the user to complete in the user profile.these are not required fields.

as i know , it must be done by using filter.

whats that filter?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm listing down the necessary hooks which will add, validate the custom fields on registration form as well as allow fields update from user profile page -

```
//show field on WordPress registration form
add_action('register_form','register_form_callback');

//handle validation
add_filter('registration_errors', 'registration_errors_callback', 10, 3);

//save user data
add_action('user_register', 'user_register_callback');
```

**seems you are looking for these**

```
//add fields on user profile page
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_user_profile_callback' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'edit_user_profile_callback' );

//handle profile update errors
add_filter('user_profile_update_errors', 'user_profile_update_errors_callback', 10, 3);

//update profile
add_action('profile_update','profile_update_callback');
```